# Lista anidada retorna pero no muestra

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ng-repeat

estoy tratando de mostrar todos los Estados de un Pais

los datos los recuper bien. pero a lamomento de mostrar en el nr-repeat es donde no muestra los registros que trae

```
$http.get('/APIs/GetPais').then(function (response) {
    $scope.ListPais = response.data;
});

$scope.GetEstado = function (CodPais) {
    $http.get("/APIs/GetEstado", { params: { CodPais: CodPais } }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

Al momento de mostrar

```
<div ng-repeat="p in ListPais" ng-init=" ListEstado = GetEstado(p.CodPais)">
    {{p.NombrePais}}
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover mb-none">
            <thead>
                <tr style="cursor:pointer">
                    <th>Nro.</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="item in ListEstado">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{item.NombreEstado}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Puede que el problema esté en que, en tu plantilla, `ListEstado` es una promesa, o un deferred, y no pueda iterarla como si fuese una lista? En Angular 2+ al menos, puede darse ese caso, no sé si angularjs funciona igual en ese aspecto

Comment: Para ese caso, como debería llamarla??? Help me!!

Comment: Solo se me ocurre que cuando se resuelva tu petición `GetEstado` asignes response.data a alguna variable de tu scope

Comment: Lo que me esta regresando en ListEstado es una cadena Json @Ilsanchez

Comment: Entiendo que esa cadena será algo como: `"[{"NombreEstado": "California", ...}, ...]"`, no? Si es asi, lo que yo haría, dentro del `then` de tu promesa: `$scope.ListaEstados = JSON.parse(response.data);`, de esta forma, en la plantilla tendrás un array de estados

Answer (score 0):

En el template tienes:

```
<div ng-repeat="p in ListPais" ng-init=" ListEstado = GetEstado(p.CodPais)">
```

Por lo que `ListEstado` espera recibir algo, posiblemente un arreglo ya que mas abajo lo pasas a un `ng-repeat`

Pero en tu controller tienes la funcion `GetEstado` expuesta al scope como:

```
$scope.GetEstado = function (CodPais) {
    $http.get("/APIs/GetEstado", { params: { CodPais: CodPais }})
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
};
```

En ningun momento retornas nada, ni tampoco mutas el estado. Mas aún, realizas una llamada a un servidor remoto por lo que la obtencion de datos es asincrona, no hay forma que la inicializacion con `ng-init` retorne en forma sincrona.

Lo que deberias hacer, es eliminar el `ng-init` del template y exponer `ListEstado` desde el controller:

```
$scope.GetEstado = function (CodPais) {
    $http.get("/APIs/GetEstado", { params: { CodPais: CodPais }})
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.ListEstado = response.data;
        });
};

...
//en algun lugar del codigo de inicializacion
$scope.GetEstado();
```